# How to define a const array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

My Code:

```
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT: string[] = ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam']
```

the error message comes from TypeScript (3.0) compiler:

> TS2322: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]'.

[image]

if I change the `string[]` to `ReadonlyArray<string>`, then the error message becomes:

> TS2322: Type 'ReadonlyArray' is not assignable to type '[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'ReadonlyArray'.

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

how can I define a readonly array in TypeScript?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, even with `strict: true`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20WEEKDAYS_SHORT%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'Dim'%2C%20'Lun'%2C%20'Mar'%2C%20'Mer'%2C%20'Jeu'%2C%20'Ven'%2C%20'Sam'%5D

Comment: hey @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I added the tsconfig.json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you point out the issue is cause because you try to assign the string array (`string[]`) to a 7-string-tuple. While your solution to use `any` will work it's not generally advisable to use `any`. Spelling out the supple is also not ideal since it's soo long.

What we can do is create a helper function to create a tuple type. This function is reusable for anywhere you need tuple:

```
function tupleArray<T extends any[]>(...v: T) {
    return v;
}
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT_INFFERED =  tupleArray('Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam')  // INFFERED AS [string, string, string, string, string, string, string]
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT: [string, string, string, string, string, string, string] = WEEKDAYS_SHORT_INFFERED
```

Comment: it works! magical! the last line can be simplified to `const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = WEEKDAYS_SHORT_INFFERED`

Comment: @Spark.Bao my point was the assignability to a variable where a tuple was expected , the type is there just to prove the point :)

Comment: you should never use any

Answer (score 58):

Assert your array declaration `as const`;

```
const readonlyArray = [1, 2, 3] as const;
```

Additionally, accessing the element type of a `readonly` array is trivial:

```
type Element = typeof readonlyArray[number]` // 1 | 2 | 3
```

`as const` assertions work on any declarations, including objects and  deeply nested data structures. You can even assert an expression `as const`. For instance, if the value `1` is inferred as a `number`, but you want to supply the number literal type, simply assert it `1 as const`.
The feature was introduced in TypeScript `3.4`. You can also reference [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Bear in that a `readonly` or `const` array is often called a tuple (as is the case in Python - [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)). Tuples can have elements of the same type or elements of entirely different types. Notice, that in the above example the `Element` type was not inferred as `number` but as a union of number literals. This is possible because the elements of the tuple are never going to change. It is practical to infer the narrowest possible type. You can, for example, use the number literal type `1` anywhere where a `number` is required, but you cannot use the `number` type where the number literal type `1` is required.

A tuple of two elements is often called a pair and may be represented as a product. Although the product of `[number, string]` is not a number, you can still multiply them together. Because both `string` and `number` are infinitely large themselves, so is their product type. Consider simpler example of `[1 | 2 | 3, 'a' | 'b' | 'c']`, which is equal to:

```
  [1, 'a']
| [1, 'b']
| [1, 'c']
| [2, 'a']
| [2, 'b']
| [2, 'c']
| [3, 'a']
| [3, 'b']
| [3, 'c']
```

Further reading:

- [readonly and const](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#readonly-and-const)
- [Product Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type)

Comment: Putting `as const` after the array like you showed worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone messed up like I did: if you want to use this snippet `type Element = typeof readonlyArray[number]`, the word `number` needs to be there even if the array has all string elements. That's because `number` refers to the array's indices, not the array's elements.

Comment: By the way, here's the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) for the `typeof readonlyArray[number]` part of the code.

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer is correct, it does have a drawback.

```
const readonlyArray = [1, 2, 3] as const;

let x = 4; // function parameter, etc.
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '1 | 2 | 3'.ts(2345)
// if (readonlyArray.includes(x)) {}
```

One alternative is to use `readonly`:

```
const readonlyArray: readonly number[] = [1, 2, 3];

let x = 4;
if (readonlyArray.includes(x)) {} // OK

// Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly number[]'.ts(2339)
// readonlyArray.push(4);
```

Comment: A way to get the first variant working is to use `any` as part of a type guard function (which would probably be good for input validation anyhow) `function isReadonlyArray(obj: any): obj is typeof readonlyArray[number] { return readonlyArray.includes(obj) }`.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging, I found it is not TypeScript compiler problem, it is because I used a third-party component call DayPicker:

```
          <DayPicker
            onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
            selectedDays={posts.day}
            months={MONTHS}
            weekdaysShort={WEEKDAYS_SHORT}
            firstDayOfWeek={1}/>
```

the type of the prop `weekdaysShort` is not `string[]`, but `[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]`

```
weekdaysShort?: [string, string, string, string, string, string, string];
```

so TS compile says `string[]` doesn't match `[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]`.

finally, I just changed the type from `string[]` to `any` to avoid this anoy error message, of course, we can change to `[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]` as well (too long).

Comment: In situations like this I find myself making a type definition, and using the type. Ie, `type WeekdaysShort = ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam']`. Then,  `const WEEKDAYS_SHORT: WeekdaysShort = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I did not reproduce the issue on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20WEEKDAYS_SHORT%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'Dim'%2C%20'Lun'%2C%20'Mar'%2C%20'Mer'%2C%20'Jeu'%2C%20'Ven'%2C%20'Sam'%5D).

But, what about using the inferred type, regardless of what it is (string array `string[]` or 7-string tuple `[string, string, string, string, string, string, string]`)?

```js
const WEEKDAYS_SHORT = ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'];
const sunday = 0;
const dayShortName = WEEKDAYS_SHORT[sunday]; // => 'Dim'
```

Or an enum?

```js
enum WEEKDAYS_SHORT { 'Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam' }
const sunday = 0;
const dayShortName = WEEKDAYS_SHORT[sunday]; // => 'Dim'
```

IMO, both option above are better than specifying the type `any` in this case.